# RavenDB Query: Have to use Customize() instead of Include()

Tags: ravendb

I'm getting an error that I'm exceeding the number of requests allowed per session (30) when using this query (using `Include` instead of `Customize`):

```
ApplicationServer appServer = QuerySingleResultAndSetEtag(session => session
    .Include<ApplicationServer>(x => x.CustomVariableGroupIds)
    .Include<ApplicationServer>(x => x.ApplicationIdsForAllAppWithGroups)
    .Include<ApplicationServer>(x => x.CustomVariableGroupIdsForAllAppWithGroups)
    .Include<ApplicationServer>(x => x.CustomVariableGroupIdsForGroupsWithinApps)
    .Include<ApplicationServer>(x => x.InstallationEnvironmentId)
    .Load <ApplicationServer>(id))
    as ApplicationServer;
```

Note, the error occurs on this line, which is called for each AppWithGroup within an application:

```
appGroup.Application = QuerySingleResultAndSetEtag(session =>
    session.Load<Application>(appGroup.ApplicationId)) as Application;
```

However, this query (using `Customize`) doesn't create extra requests:

```
ApplicationServer appServer = QuerySingleResultAndSetEtag(session =>
    session.Query<ApplicationServer>()
    .Customize(x => x.Include<ApplicationServer>(y => y.CustomVariableGroupIds))
    .Customize(x => x.Include<ApplicationServer>(y => y.ApplicationIdsForAllAppWithGroups))
    .Customize(x => x.Include<ApplicationServer>(y => y.CustomVariableGroupIdsForAllAppWithGroups))
    .Customize(x => x.Include<ApplicationServer>(y => y.CustomVariableGroupIdsForGroupsWithinApps))
    .Customize(x => x.Include<ApplicationServer>(y => y.InstallationEnvironmentId))
    .Where(server => server.Id == id).FirstOrDefault())
    as ApplicationServer;
```

However, the above query causes an error:

> Attempt to query by id only is blocked, you should use call
>   session.Load("applications/2017"); instead of
>   session.Query().Where(x=>x.Id == "applications/2017");
>
> You can turn this error off by specifying
>   documentStore.Conventions.AllowQueriesOnId = true;, but that is not
>   recommend and provided for backward compatibility reasons only.

I had to set `AllowQueriesOnId = true` because it was the only way I could get this to work.

**What am I doing wrong in the first query to cause the includes not to work?**

By the way, [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10753857/279516) had the same issue where he had to use `Customize`. I'd like to do this correctly though.

Comment: `QuerySingleResultAndSetEtag` is nonstandard.  If you're still having this issue, then please post the code for that function as well so we can see the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the load isn't doing this for you, What version of raven are you on? I just tested this in Raven 2.5 build 2700 and the include is bringing back the information for me in a single request.

Anyway, with the load not working quite like i would expect, i would switch to a set of lazy queries to get what you want in 2 server round trips. http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/querying/lazy-operations.

Another option that might work out better for you, (depending on what you are really doing with all of that data) is a transformer. http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/querying/results-transformation/result-transformers?version=2.5

Hope that helps.